# How to enable these SQL Server PowerShell commands?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

On [this Microsoft documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlps/?view=sqlserver-ps), it lists a lot of SQL Server PowerShell commands. But how can I use it? Should I install anything? I just installed SQL Server 2016 (without SSMS) and it seems that I can't use these commands.

```
PS C:\> gcm Enable-SqlAlwaysOn
gcm : The term 'Enable-SqlAlwaysOn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gcm Enable-SqlAlwaysOn
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-SqlAlwaysOn:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand

PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable *sql*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you followed the instructions to install the SQL Server Powershell Module?

```
Install-Module -Name SqlServer
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16